# Syntax to match a string in square bracktets (like `[a string]`)?

Tags: syntax, glob, expect

I'm rather new to expect (and TCL), but not new to programming.
However I'm fighting a problem I cannot solve (using expect 5.45):

I want to match (`expect`) a string like `[detached from ...]`, but I did not succeed:

- `-gl "\[detached from *\]"` is treated as a character class, matching single characters repeatedly.
- `-gl "\\[detached from *\\]"` seems to be identical to `-gl "[detached from *]"`, causing an error like "**invalid command name "detached"**".

Obviously I cannot use `-ex(act)` as the `...` part is variable.

Comment: not sure if you have to match against `[` and `]`, otherwise just use `expect "detached from *"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the double quotes, you need:

```
expect -gl  "\\\[detached from *\\\]"
```

The first 2 slashes are to put a literal slash in the pattern.
The 3rd slash is to escape the bracket from being interpreted as command substitution.

Simpler though would be to use braces (Tcl's equivalent of the shell single quotes

```
expect -gl  {\[detached from *\]}
```

Comment: Can you explain why a single backslash isn't enough, and why two backslashes behave like no backslash at all? Is it that `\[` just prevents function call, and then "consumes" the backslash, and `\\` would just put a single backslash in from of the function's result?

Comment: Referring to the Tcl [12 syntax rules](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M16):

Answer (score 0):

Giving my own alternative answer (ordered by number of backslashes):

- `-gl "[detached from *]"` does *command substitution* (call a function named `detached` with `from` and `*` being treated as parameters to the function.
- `-gl "\[detached from *\]"` does prevent *command substitution*, but `[` introduces a character class for the matching engine, so the string won't match literally.
- `-gl "\\[detached from *\\]"` adds a literal `\` in front of `[detached from *]` (which is still interpreted as *command substitution*.
- `-gl "\\\[detached from *\\\]"` adds a literal `\` (leaving `\[...`), thus also *escaping* command substitution, so the matching engine will see `\[...\]`, treating `[` literally (and not as the start of a character class).